# How many Parallel thread can I have in Selenium standalone project

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, testng

Currently I am using selenium standalone project with parallel threading. I am using 10 threads. However I want to make it fast. How many maximum thread I can have? OR should I move to Grid? Please advice.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

**How many maximum thread I can have?**   - this depends on your PC resources, is not a specific limit.

I suggest using TestNg or Selenium Grid.